# Replace end of string with dots if word is longer then X

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I format a string in a Razor CSHTML page if it's longer then X caracters:

```
<p>@Model.Council</p> 

Example for an X = 9

-> if Council is "Lisbon", then the result is "<p>Lisbon</p>"
-> if Council is "Vila Real de Santo António", then the result is "<p>Vila Real...</p>" with the title over the <p> "Vila Real de Santo António" showing the complete information
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for any string. [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e8681e3d-4d9e-4757-82fb-fc6c629b346d).

And for your code...

```
@(Model.Council.Length>10 ? Model.Council.Substring(0, 10)+"..." : Model.Council)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I decided for your solution due to his simplicity. Thanks again.

Comment: thats an exact duplicate of my answer

Comment: It was before you, or at the same time. :(

Comment: @(item.Title.length > 10 ? item.Title.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : item.Title)
I get this error. any idea?
 CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Found it, it should be .Length not .length

Comment: Fixed in original. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a helper method you can use:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    //Truncates a string to be no longer than a certain length
    public static string TruncateWithEllipsis(string s, int length)
    {
        //there may be a more appropiate unicode character for this
        const string Ellipsis = "...";

        if (Ellipsis.Length > length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", length, "length must be at least as long as ellipsis.");

        if (s.Length > length)
            return s.Substring(0, length - Ellipsis.Length) + Ellipsis;
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Just call it from inside of your CSHTML:

```
<p>@StringHelper.TruncateWithEllipsis(Model.Council, 10)</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.Console.Length <= 9 ? Model.Console : Model.Console.Substring(0, 9) + "...";
```

this is using a [Tirany Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It checks if the length is less then or equal to 9, if it is then use the left side after ? , if its false , use the right side, which will cut off the string after 9 chars and append `"..."`

you can put this right inline in your razor code , whit out having to call any code from the view.

Note - this may break if `Model.Console` is null or empty

Answer (score 1):

Just as an option, a Regex.Replace (although it's probably easier to make it a function and use a regular `Substring`)

```
Regex.Replace("Vila Real de Santo António", "^(.{9}).+", "$1...")
```